# Using instances of generic types as return value type in a Hyperledger chain code written in GO

Tags: go, hyperledger-chaincode

In my project, I am using a wrapper structure, that is defined similar to this:

```golang
type Wrapper[T any] struct {
   Foo  int
   Data T
}
```

Additionally, my chain code offers a method with the following signature

```golang
func(contract *MyContract) DoSomething() *Wrapper[mypkg.Bar]
```

where `Bar` is a simple structure defined - for example - like this:

```golang
package mypkg

struct Bar {
  Foo string
  Bar string
}
```

Anyhow, if I try to deploy my chaincode, I get the following error:

```
Error compiling schema for MyContract[DoSomething]. Return schema invalid. Object has no key 'Wrapper[[]<part of module name>'
```

Strangely, the part with `Wrapper[[]<part of module name>` is cropped. So only part of the module name is showing, and, as you can see, the bracketing is wrong: The second closing bracket is missing (so that is not a mistake made by me). The name of my module is the link to the GitHub repository.

I have tried to manually replace the generic type `T` in `Wrapper` with `Bar` by creating the structure

```golang
type WrapperBar struct {
  Foo int
  Data Bar
}
```

If I now adapt the function signature to

```golang
func(contract *MyContract) DoSomething() *WrapperBar
```

it works just fine. Unfortunately, I am using the structure `Wrapper` several times with different
type instantiations. So although creating all the types manually would be a workaround, it is obviously not a very elegant one.

Is there another workaround so that I can still use my generic `Wrapper` structure?
I am currently using `go` in version `1.18` and `fabric-contract-api-go` in version `v1.1.1`.

Answer (score 2):

The Go contract-api at this time doesn't support Go Generics, the only workarounds I can suggest are the one that you have tried noted in this question or to write your chaincode without using the contract API, there is an example here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/chaincode/marbles02/go of an implementation that doesn't use the contract-api.
Your implemention will have to do more work in your chaincode such as providing your own method dispatching, validating and unmarshalling the input data

You could raise an issue at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go and ideally also contribute a PR that addresses this issue as I can't say when or if this would ever be supported.